# Fluctuational Electrodynamics: Ensemble Average

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, fluctuation-dissipation

I am trying to understand the ensemble average often stated in the fluctuation-dissipation theorem describing thermal radiation:

[image]

Here, the overbar denotes the ensemble average. My question is, how is this average calculated? Is it averaged over time or frequency? Spatial average?
My understanding of ensemble average is an average over many possible configurations of the system. Many papers state the above equation and definition. However, I can't find an explicit expansion of the ensemble average term in the above equation.

The equation is taken from:

Otey, Clayton R., et al. "Fluctuational electrodynamics calculations of near-field heat transfer in non-planar geometries: A brief overview." Journal of Quantitative Spectroscopy and Radiative Transfer 132 (2014): 3-11.

Comment: It is an ensemble average, so it is average over some ensemble, perhaps the canonical ensemble. Mathematically, it is integral over some probability distribution of states of the system.

Comment: Thanks very much.